# Return a specific field from elasticsearch index or update query

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Here is a part of my code for index or update document. I want to get a specific field value 'documentID' which is in '_source'.Here 'json' is JSONObject of document model.

```
 String jsonForUpdate = json.toString();
    String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    json.put("documentID", uuid);
    String jsonForIndex = json.toString();   
    IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest(indexName, typeName, documentModel.getId());
    indexRequest.source(jsonForIndex);
    UpdateResponse updateResponse = elasticsearchTemplate.getClient().prepareUpdate(indexName, typeName , documentModel.getId()).setDoc(jsonForUpdate).setUpsert(indexRequest).setFields("documentID").get();
```

I tried this code to get value for document field.

```
updateResponse.getGetResult().getFields().get("documentID").getValue().toString();
```

But it didnt work for me during updating the document.works fine during indexing the document.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html

you can see the following parameter that can be passed on update:

```
_source

Allows to control if and how the updated source should be returned in the response. By default the updated source is not returned. See source filtering for details.
```

This mean that in your `prepareUpdate` you can use the `setFetchSource(true)` method, although this will bring the full document.

**Update:**
For version 2.3.3 you can still use:

```
/**
 * Explicitly specify the fields that will be returned. By default, nothing is returned.
 */
public UpdateRequestBuilder setFields(String... fields) {
    request.fields(fields);
    return this;
}
```

Elasticsearch doc: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/docs-update.html

The method is available on the UpdateRequestBuilder, which is the class of the object returned by your prepareUpdate.

Comment: I am using ElasticsearchTemplate.there is no option for setFetchSource(true)

Comment: Have you tried:     UpdateResponse updateResponse = elasticsearchTemplate.getClient().prepareUpdate(indexName, typeName , documentModel.getId()).setFetchSource(true).setDoc(jsonForUpdate).setU psert(indexRequest).setFields("documentID").get();
?

Comment: There is no option for setFetchFields(true).

Comment: It's not setFetchFields(true) but setFetchSource(true), I tested it earlier so I find that very doubtful, unless you're using a very old version

Comment: There is no option for setFetchSource(true) also

Comment: In that case you're using a very old version, probably 2 or similar which might not have it, which in turn means that what you want is not possible. Elasticsearch is currently on version 5.5, I would advise to update

Comment: elasticsearch version i am using is 2.3.3 .

Comment: you can still use:

public UpdateRequestBuilder setFetchSource(@ Nullable String include, @ Nullable String exclude) {
        request.fetchSource(include, exclude);
        return this;
    }

or event the deprecated:
 @ Deprecated
    public UpdateRequestBuilder setFields(String... fields) {
        DEPRECATION_LOGGER.deprecated("Deprecated field [fields] used, expected [_source] instead");
        request.fields(fields);
        return this;
    }

Elasticsearch doc: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/docs-update.html

Comment: Ignore java from last comment, that's for version 5 still, for version 2.3.3 it's:

public UpdateRequestBuilder setFields(String... fields) {
        request.fields(fields);
        return this;
    }

Comment: Thanks for help. When i use UpdateQueryBuilder update and index document will not work properly. Indexing document will be fine using upsert.because '.doc(source)' is used for both update and index. UpdateQueryBuilder will not use '.upsert(indexRequest)'  for update.Thats why i didnt use that method.However when i change 'getClient().get()' into 'getClient().actionGet()' it works as i expected –

Comment: Good to know :) BUT, you do use UpdateQueryBuilder, here -> prepareUpdate(indexName, typeName , documentModel.getId()) -> this returns an instance of UpdateQueryBuilder. But what matters is that it is working :) Congrats